# Azure AD B2C policy usage

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Shall I use built in userflow for signup/signin and custom policy for forgot password in same react js application?

Comment: Yes, you should

Comment: yes, you can use that.

Comment: You can do that. But why ask? custom policies are designed primarily to address complex scenarios. So whether to use custom policy depends on whether you need it.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

A **sign-up or sign-in** user flow with local accounts includes a **Forgot password?** link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow.

Instead, the error code `AADB2C90118` is returned to your application. Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. To see an example, take a look at a simple [ASP.NET sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI) that demonstrates the linking of user flows.

Reference:

https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/83